# How to pass apostrophe in var as it is without replacing it in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to pass NewText value as it is in .cs code via ajax call.

```
**var NewText ="D'souza";**
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "frmLabel.aspx/getText",
                data: **"{newtext:'" + NewText + "'}",**
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (gridData) {
                    text = gridData.d;
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Did you tried escaping the apostrophe like `"D\'souza"`

Comment: Try this

var data = {"newtext" : "D'souza"},
    payload = JSON.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
  ...
  data: payload,
  ....
  });

Comment: It solved,by doing this NewText = NewText .replace(/'/g, "&apos;");

Answer (score 3):

```
**var NewText ="D\'souza";**
```

Use escaping of '

Comment: throws Unrecognized escape sequence  data: "{newtext:'D\'souza '}"

Comment: try using "D\\'souza"

Answer (score 0):

A possibly better alternative to escaping only apostrophes would be to encode the supplied string with the use of 'encodeURIComponent(newText)'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `'`.

```
var NewText ="D\'souza";
```

Or just use [`template strings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

```
var NewText = `D'souza`;
...
...
data: `{newtext:'${NewText}'}`,
```

Comment: Template strings can only be used with ES6